# Sort Custom Post Type by Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, loops

How can you sort a custom post type by a custom field in Wordpress? I'm trying to figure out a way to echo a custom field called 'State' *alphabetically* and place the custom post type links called employees under each of their respect states.

So it would look like this:

**Alabama**

- Appleseed, Johnny
- Chamber, Pete

**Florida**

- Miller, Sam
- Stark, Amy

  I know how to write the basic loop for a custom post type but I'm not sure how to sort under a custom field belonging to that post type alphabetically.

  ```
  <?php $query = new WP_query ( array( 'post_type'=> 'employees', 'meta_key'=> 'state', 
   'orderby'=> 'meta_value', 'order' => 'DESC'));
     while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'state', true); ?>
   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php
  endwhile;   
  wp_reset_query();  ?>
  ```

Comment: How can I echo each state name (custom field) and group each custom post underneath of it's state like the example above?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php $query = new WP_query ( array( 'post_type'=> 'employees', 'meta_key'=> 'state', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value', 'order' => 'DESC'));
  while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php
endwhile;   
wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Comment: That kind of answers my question. What I'm really after is being able to sort all the posts under that state. So if the state is Virginia it would show all employees under that state and so on. I need to figure out how I can loop through each state and display all of the employees under their respective states like my example above. I don't want to echo every state for each post. I want them all grouped together. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it thanks to this link: http://pastebin.com/b4WGrMhD

```
<?php $employeesQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'employees', 'meta_key' => 'state', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '-1')); ?>
  <?php $prevltr = ""; ?>
    <?php if(have_posts()) { while ( $employeesQuery->have_posts() ) { $employeesQuery->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $state = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'state', true); ?>
            <?php $curltr = $state; ?>
            <?php if($curltr != $prevltr) : ?>
                <a name="section-<?php echo $curltr ?>"></a><br class="clear" /><h4><?php echo $curltr; $prevltr = $curltr; ?></h4>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <article class="employee-entry" id="entry-<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

                <div><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong></div>
                <div><?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'titles' ); foreach( $terms as $term ) { print $term->name; unset($term); } ?></div>

            </article>

<?php }} ?>
```